# Create a super column using CQL3

Tags: cassandra, cql3

I am upgrading my thrift api to cql3. My data contains SuperColumns as follows:

```
- User                                  //column family
    - Division/name                     //my row key
     -DivHead                              //SuperColumn
       - name                              //Columns
       - address                           //Columns
```

I understand all the column families to be changed to tables. And the primary key becomes the rowkey. So rest are the columns.

But my data has supercolumns. how do I create supercolumns using CQL3?

Comment: cql3 doesnt support supercolumn family creation instead it promotes using composite columns. check this link http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_intro_c.html

Comment: though it provides backward compatibility

Comment: You mean to say i need to use composite partition key??
CREATE TABLE User (
row_keyname varchar,
div_name text,
name text,
address text,
PRIMARY KEY ((row_keyname, div_name), name,address);
Is this right for my example?
);

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE user (
  rowkey varchar,
  division text,
  head_name text,
  address text,
  PRIMARY KEY (rowkey, division)
)

OR

CREATE TABLE user (
  rowkey varchar,
  division text,
  head_name text,
  head_address text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((rowkey, division))
)

Under the covers the first example will have each rowkey assigned to the same partition. Each  rowkey will have a set of logical rows, one for each division. Those rows will contain two columns: head_name and head_address. You can query based on the rowkey and get all divisions (sorted!). Or you can query a rowkey with a range of divisions or a single division and get a subset of the divisions with their division head and address.

The second example will have one partition for each rowkey and division combination. Each such partition will be one logical row as well. The single row for each composite key will have two columns: head_name and head_address. To make a query, you must provide BOTH the rowkey and the division.

EDIT: Cleared up some bad grammar.

Comment: I didn't want to mention this in my actual answer, but I thought it would be good to mention:
1) CQL does not handle mixed case very well, you should probably drop all table and column names to lower case if you can afford to make the change.
2) I'm assuming you don't have a one-to-one correlation of rowkey and division. Otherwise, why not just use the division name as your primary key?